# How do I run function during useEffect, and on demand via button click

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework, react-hooks

I have a function that I need to run once on page render and a second time whenever a button is clicked. So, I added the function call in a useEffect as below:

```
  const getBtStatus = async () => {
    try {
      await BleClient.initialize();
      let isBtEnabled = await BleClient.isEnabled();
      setIsBtEnabled(isBtEnabled);
      if (!isBtEnabled) {
          setMessage("BT not enabled, or not supported!");
      }
    } catch (e) {
      catchError(e, "Bluetooth Unavailable");
    }
  };


  useEffect(() => {
    getBtStatus();
  }, [])
```

This compiles but the terminal shows the following warning:

> React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'getBtStatus'. Either
> include it or remove the dependency array

So, I've changed the useEffect to this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    getBtStatus();
  }, [getBtStatus])
```

Which now result in the following output:

> The 'getBtStatus' function makes the dependencies of useEffect Hook
> (at line 64) change on every render. To fix this, wrap the definition
> of 'getBtStatus' in its own useCallback() Hook

If I now convert getBtStatus to use useCallback, what do I use for an argument to ensure that it is updated whenever called from the reset button? eg:

```
const getBtStatus = useCallback(async () => {
  try {
    await BleClient.initialize();
    let isBtEnabled = await BleClient.isEnabled();
    setIsBtEnabled(isBtEnabled);
    if (!isBtEnabled) {
      setMessage("BT not enabled, or not supported!");
    }
  } catch (e) {
    catchError(e, "Bluetooth Unavailable");
  }
}, []);
```

So far I've tried leaving an empty array as the useCallback dependency but getBtStatus isn't re-rendered on clicking the reset button. Likewise I've tried creating a useState const:bool that gets
set to true when clicking on the reset but and is set to false when getbtStatus is run, then this const is set as the dependency for getBtStatus. However, none of these are causing the getBtStatus function to run when the reset button is clicked.

I'm stuck now as to what I should try next. It seems I'm not understanding how this works.

As requested here is the reset function that is run when clicking the reset button:

```
const reset = async () => {
    try {
      await BleClient.initialize();
      setMessage("Disconnected");
      setLoading(false);
      setIsConnected(false);
      setData([]);
      setDevices([]);
      setSelectedDevice({});
      setServices([]);
      setDoReset(true);

      const prefixFilter = localStorage.getItem("prefix")
      const optionalService = localStorage.getItem("optionalService")
      if (prefixFilter) {
        setPrefixFilter(prefixFilter);
      }
      if (optionalService) {
        setOptionalService(optionalService);
      }
      getBtStatus();
    } catch (e) {
      catchError(e, "Cannot Disconnect Error");
    }
  };
```

Comment: I've updated the post with the reset function.

Comment: What is indicating to you that the getBtStatus function isn't running when you call reset()?

Comment: "If I now convert getBtStatus to use useCallback, what do I use for an argument to ensure that it is updated whenever called from the reset button?" useCallback just memoizes the callback based on the values in your dependency array. Each time your component renders, React will diff the dependencies you specify - if they're the same, useCallback will return the memoized callback. If they're not, it will return a new function. Since your function only references a setter returned by useState (which React guarantees to have a stable identity), your function still should be getting called.

Comment: My point is that if your function isn't acting as expected when you click the reset button, I have a feeling there's something else going on besides a misuse of useCallback()

Comment: Unless you're doing something wild like instantiating BleClient in the component or something

Comment: In the getBtStatus function I added a console.log line which i would expect to see whenever the function is run. however, I am only seeing it on the page load and not when calling the function via the reset button.

Comment: If I remove all the useEffect and useCallback code and just hit the reset button, then I see the console.logging work as expected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239892/discussion-between-brendan-bond-and-phill-healey).